# Minimal polynomial- fields

Tags: polynomials

Let $\zeta$ = $\cos(\frac{2\pi}{7} ) + i\sin(\frac{2\pi}{7} )$ , let $\alpha = \zeta +\zeta^{-1} $  note that $\zeta^{-1} =\zeta^6 $

I try to find the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb Q$. 
I only managed to show that the degree of the minimal polynomial is 3. 
My attempt so far:

$\alpha^3 = \zeta^3+ 3\zeta^{-1}\zeta^2+3\zeta\zeta^{-2}+\zeta^{18}  = \zeta^3+\zeta^4+3\alpha            $

And I don't know how to continue, Thank you for your help

Comment: שלום. When you wrote $\zeta^{18}$ did you mean $\zeta^{-3}$?

Comment: Look up [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1150009/11619), or many other places. Like [this search list](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x%5E3%2Bx%5E2-2x-1%24&p=1) or [this](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Czeta%20%2B%5Czeta%5E%7B-1%7D%24%2C%207&p=2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now add the equation
$$
α^4=ζ^4+ζ^{-4}+4(ζ^2+ζ^{-2})+6=ζ^4+ζ^3+4α^2-2
$$
to your consideration to find that
$$
α^4-α^3-4α^2+3α+2=0
$$
This has a root at $2=1+1^{-1}$, the remaining factor is
$$
α^3 + α^2 - 2α - 1=0
$$

---

You could of course also start at
$$
0=\frac{ζ^7-1}{ζ-1}=1+ζ+ζ^2+ζ^3+ζ^4+ζ^5+ζ^6=1+α+(α^2-2)+(α^3-3α)
$$

Comment: Thanks !!, how did you know that 2 is a root of the polynomial?

Comment: Because in that derivation up to that point $ζ=1$ is also a valid root of $ζ^7-1=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\zeta^7=1$ and $\zeta\ne1$ so $\color{red}{\zeta^6}+\color{purple}{\zeta^5}+\color{blue}{\zeta^4+\zeta^3}+\color{purple}{\zeta^2}+\color{red}{\zeta}+1=0$.

Now $\alpha=\zeta^{-1}+\zeta,  \alpha^2=\zeta^{-2}+\zeta^2+2, $ and $\alpha^3=\zeta^{-3}+\zeta^3+3\zeta^{-1}+3\zeta$,

so we have $\color{red}\alpha+\color{purple}{\alpha^2-2}+\color{blue}{\alpha^3-3\alpha}+1=0$ or $\alpha^3+\alpha^2-2\alpha-1=0$.

Comment: Note that $\zeta^{-1}=\zeta^6, \zeta^{-2}=\zeta^5, $ and $\zeta^{-3}=\zeta^4$